# Sorted Enumeration in DataGrid Combo Column

Tags: wpf, vb.net, datagrid

I am try to have an enumeration in my datagrid combo box column, but have it sorted by name and still be able to bind the selected option to object that is the source of the grid.

I have tried Two different ways of accomplishing this.

**Enum Declaration**

```
public enum Animals
Zebra
Antelope
Ox
Mouse
End Enum
```

**XAML Enum Reference**

```
xmlns:obj="clr-namespace:SMS_Obj.Enumerations;assembly=SMS_Obj"
xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
xmlns:scm="clr-namespace:System.ComponentModel;assembly=WindowsBase"

<CollectionViewSource x:Key="AnimalEnum">
            <CollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions>
                <scm:SortDescription />
            </CollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions>

            <CollectionViewSource.Source>
                <ObjectDataProvider MethodName="GetNames" ObjectType="{x:Type sys:Enum}">
                    <ObjectDataProvider.MethodParameters>
                        <x:Type TypeName="obj:Animals" />
                    </ObjectDataProvider.MethodParameters>
                </ObjectDataProvider>
            </CollectionViewSource.Source>
        </CollectionViewSource>
```

**Object Set as ItemsSource for the Grid**

List OF

```
    Public Class clsAnimals

    Private _AnimalID As SMS_Obj.Enumerations.Animals
    Public Property AnimalID() As SMS_Obj.Enumerations.Animals
        Get
            Return _AnimalID
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As SMS_Obj.Enumerations.Animals)
            _AnimalID = value
        End Set
    End Property

End Class
```

**Attempt 1**

```
 <DataGridComboBoxColumn x:Name="dgcAnimalName" Header="Animal Name" Width="*" SelectedValueBinding="{Binding Path=AnimalID, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource AnimalEnum},Mode=OneWay}" />
```

**Attempt 2**

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn x:Name="dgcAnimalName" Header="Animal Name" Width="*">
<DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <ComboBox DataContext="{StaticResource AnimalEnum}" SelectedValuePath="{Binding Path=AnimalsID, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" ItemsSource="{Binding}"/>
    </DataTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
<DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <ComboBox DataContext="{StaticResource AnimalEnum}" SelectedValuePath="{Binding Path=AnimalID, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" ItemsSource="{Binding}"/>
    </DataTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
```

Both attempts Bind the enumeration correctly but i lose the values that are on the object already and any new values.  I think there is something that I am missing as I have never used a sorted Enum in XAML before.

Thank you in Advance

Answer (score 0):

The Reason that its not Binding is because the GetNames call, makes the `SelectedValue` a string and not an Integer.  I was able to get it to work by changing the object to

```
Private _AnimalID  As SMS_Obj.Enumerations.Animals
Public Property AnimalID() As SMS_Obj.Enumerations.Animals
Get
    Return _AnimalID 
End Get
Set(ByVal value As SMS_Obj.Enumerations.Animals)
    _AnimalID  = value
    If _TableName <> [Enum].GetName(GetType(SMS_Obj.Enumerations.Animals), _AnimalID ) Then
        _TableName = [Enum].GetName(GetType(SMS_Obj.Enumerations.Animals), _AnimalID )
    End If
End Set
End Property
Private _AnimalName As String
Public Property AnimalName() As String
Get
    Return _AnimalName
End Get
Set(ByVal value As String)
    _AnimalName = value
    If _AnimalID  <> [Enum].Parse(GetType(SMS_Obj.Enumerations.Animals), _AnimalName) Then
        _AnimalID  = [Enum].Parse(GetType(SMS_Obj.Enumerations.Animals), _AnimalName)
    End If
End Set
End Property
```

And the Binding to this:

```
 <DataGridComboBoxColumn x:Name="dgcAnimalName" Header="Animal Name" Width="*" SelectedValueBinding="{Binding Path=AnimalName, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource AnimalEnum},Mode=OneWay}" />
```